# Resizing vectors c++

Tags: c++, vector

```
struct struct1
{
    vector<unsigned> vec1;
};

void main()
{
    vector<struct1> vecStruct1;
    struct1 obj1Struct1;
    struct1 obj2Struct1;
    vecStruct1.push_back(obj1Struct1);
    vecStruct1.push_back(obj2Struct1);
}
```

Now if I resize `vec1` of `struct1` of object `vecStruct1[0]`, then is it also the case that `vecStruct1` also gets resized i.e. will it cause reallocation in `vecStruct1` i.e.  will `&vecStruct[0]` and `&vecStruct[1]` not be different after resizing `vec1` of `vecStruct1[0]`?

Comment: Are you sure that you can't make this question simplier...? These two lines of question are pretty evil :)

Comment: @irchris102 I mean will &vecStruct[0] and &vecStruct[1] be the same after resizing vecStruct[0]

Comment: As a suggestion, rename your vectors to something that stands out more, like "innerVector" or "outVector", whatever you want. Your current names are slightly confusing ;)

Comment: @aslg ok..will be more careful in future

Comment: Now would be a good start though. Helps you more than us.

Answer (score 3):

Nope, `vector` stores its element on the heap not inside itself in the structure, so the `vector` per se never grows when you resize it, what grows is the data buffer pointed by `vector`.

Comment: are you sure std::vector stores elements in heap and not consecutively in continous memory location...can you please point me from some source from which I can learn more

Comment: They are consecutive, but in the heap.

Comment: i am not getting how can they be consecutive in heap..can you point me to some source from which I can learn more about it

Comment: @JannatArora Think about it, how would you resize if there were stored in the structure, how do you resize a structure when it is a compile time entity? There is even no way to change `sizeof(std::vector)` at compile time, let alone at run time :)

Comment: @JannatArora They stored consecutively in the heap because every time you add a new element that exceeds the current capacity of the vector the whole bunch of old elements are moved to a new buffer able to store them all plus the new one (at least). In short they are continuously moved to stay together whenever the buffer size is not big enough for the next insertion.

Comment: @Drax Thanks but i am still not getting will  &vecStruct[0] and &vecStruct[1] be the same after resizing vecStruct[0]

Comment: @Drax Thanks so does that mean the values of &vecStruct[0] and vecStruct[1] be different after resizing

Comment: @JannatArora As long as you do not resize vecStruct itself, its elements do not move. So `&vecStruct[0]` and `&vecStruct[1]` do not change if you don't resize/grow `vecStruct` itself.

Answer (score 2):

As `vecStruct1` contain copy of `obj1Struct1`, once the object is added, the 2 object are distinct.

so modify `obj1Struct1` doesn't modify `vecStruct1[0]`.

Comment: will &vecStruct[0] and &vecStruct[1] will not be different after resizing vecStruct[0]

Comment: @JannatArora; After `vecStruct.resize(..)`, `&vecStruct[0]` may have changed. After `vecStruct1[0].vec1.resize(..)`, `&vecStruct[0]` doesn't change.

Comment: this answer answered the question as it was originally phrased, but no longer answers the modified question.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this example will clarify the situation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct struct1
{
    vector<unsigned> vec1;
};

int main() {

    vector<struct1> vecStruct1;
    struct1 obj1Struct1;
    struct1 obj2Struct1;
    vecStruct1.push_back(obj1Struct1);
    vecStruct1.push_back(obj2Struct1);

    cout << "Before resizing the vector:" << endl;
    cout << "Address of vecStruct1[0]:" << &vecStruct1[0] << endl;
    cout << "Address of vecStruct1[1]:" << &vecStruct1[1] << endl;
    cout << "Capacity of the vector in vecStruct1[0]:" << vecStruct1[0].vec1.capacity() << endl;
    cout << "Capacity of the vector in vecStruct1[1]:" << vecStruct1[1].vec1.capacity() << endl;
    cout << endl;


    vecStruct1[0].vec1.resize(1000);

    cout << "After resizing vecStruct1[0]:" << endl;
    cout << "Address of vecStruct1[0]:" << &vecStruct1[0] << endl;
    cout << "Address of vecStruct1[1]:" << &vecStruct1[1] << endl;
    cout << "Capacity of the vector in vecStruct1[0]:" << vecStruct1[0].vec1.capacity() << endl;
    cout << "Capacity of the vector in vecStruct1[1]:" << vecStruct1[1].vec1.capacity() << endl;
    cout << endl;


    vecStruct1[1].vec1.resize(2000);

    cout << "After resizing vecStruct1[1]:" << endl;
    cout << "Address of vecStruct1[0]:" << &vecStruct1[0] << endl;
    cout << "Address of vecStruct1[1]:" << &vecStruct1[1] << endl;
    cout << "Capacity of the vector in vecStruct1[0]:" << vecStruct1[0].vec1.capacity() << endl;
    cout << "Capacity of the vector in vecStruct1[1]:" << vecStruct1[1].vec1.capacity() << endl;
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output (you can check it on ideone: http://ideone.com/JVaiqg) is:

```
Before resizing the vector:
Address of vecStruct1[0]:0x8f33018
Address of vecStruct1[1]:0x8f33024
Capacity of the vector in vecStruct1[0]:0
Capacity of the vector in vecStruct1[1]:0

After resizing vecStruct1[0]:
Address of vecStruct1[0]:0x8f33018
Address of vecStruct1[1]:0x8f33024
Capacity of the vector in vecStruct1[0]:1000
Capacity of the vector in vecStruct1[1]:0

After resizing vecStruct1[1]:
Address of vecStruct1[0]:0x8f33018
Address of vecStruct1[1]:0x8f33024
Capacity of the vector in vecStruct1[0]:1000
Capacity of the vector in vecStruct1[1]:2000
```

And as you can see, the address of `vecStruct1[0]` and `vecStruct1[1]` never changes. That's because each element of the vector has a fixed size, and internally it contains a pointer to the area where the resized vectors are stored. When you resize the vectors (the "internal" ones, that is, each `vec1` inside each `struct1`) it's possible that they have to be moved to a new address, but the "external" vector `vecStruct1` stays where it is.

Answer (score 1):

No, the two vectors are totally unrelated. Adding elements to one vector, or resizing it some other way, will not cause any other vector to become resized.

Also, resizing `vecStruct1[0].vec1` will not resize `vecStruct1[1].vec1`.

---

Clarifications:

If you have a pointer to the first element in `vecStruct1` (i.e. `&vecStruct1[0]`) that pointer will be invalidated if you resize `vecStruct1`. What you do with `vecStruct1[0].vec1` doesn't matter here, and pointer to element in `vecStruct1[0].vec1` will not change.

And if you have a pointer `&(vecStruct1[0].vec1[0])` (parentheses not needed but added for clarity) then if you resize `vecStruct1` that pointer will not change. You need to resize `vecStruct1[0].vec1` for that pointer to become invalid.

Comment: I am not saying that the other vector will be resized..all I am saying is will vecStruct1 be resized i.e. will &vecStruct[0] and &vecStruct[1] will not be different after resizig

Comment: @JannatArora Okay, so I should have kept my initial answer which said that the element indexes will never change, but the location *might* change invalidating pointers, references and iterators.

Comment: @JannatArora But that's not really what you're saying in your question... You seem to ask if resizing `vec1` will also resize `vecStruct1`.

Comment: I am sorry I am a little poor at framing questions..but I am constantly striving to improve this skill....but all I am asking is will &vecStruct[0] and &vecStruct[1] will not be different after resizing. Perhaps a little example illustrating this will help me big way

Comment: Between Drax seems to be contradicting what you are saying

Comment: @JannatArora We're saying the same thing, but your question is ambiguous because it depends **what** you resize, if you resize the parent vector they change if you resize one of the child vector there is no change.

Comment: @JannatArora Not really, Drax doesn't say *how* the buffer grows, and it really doesn't matter. All you need to know that if the vector have been resized, all pointer, references and iterators to elements in the vector are invalidated.

Comment: @JannatArora What "parent vector"? What "child vector"? Like I say in my answer, all vectors you show in the code in your question are distinct different vectors, there's no parent-child relationship, resizing one vector won't affect any other vector.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Yes, will be pointers, references and iterators of vecStruct1 change after resizing vec1 in vecStruct1[0]

Comment: @Drax I am resizing the child vector vecStruct1[0], so will &vecStruct1[0] and &vecStruct1[1] change after resizing

Comment: @JannatArora As said in the first word of my answer: Nope :)

Answer (score 0):

The vector handles its memory outside of the structure, in the heap as mentioned in another answer. So resizing or reallocating the vector inside the structure won't change the structure's size at all, not even the vector containing that structure.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/

The vector handles its own memory dynamically ( in the heap ).